# Optimizing an algorithm on adjacent digits

Tags: java

I am given two integers ‘n’ and ‘m’, and I have to find all the stepping numbers in range [n, m]. A number is called stepping number if all adjacent digits have an absolute difference of 2. 131 is a Stepping Number while 421 is not.The problem I face is that I have to print them in sorted order without repetition of the numbers from smallest to biggest but my algorithm prints them randomly and also M can be maximum 10^30 ,which when set my program runs out of memory.Any suggestions how can I do this?

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {

public static void bfs(Long n, Long m, Long num) {

    Queue<Long> q = new LinkedList<Long>();

    q.add(num);

    while (!q.isEmpty()) {

        Long stepNum = q.poll();

        if (stepNum <= m && stepNum >= n) {

            System.out.print(stepNum+" ");
        }

        if (stepNum == 0 || stepNum > m)
            continue;

        Long lastDigit = stepNum % 10;

        Long stepNumA = stepNum * 10 + (lastDigit - 2);
        Long stepNumB = stepNum * 10 + (lastDigit + 2);

        if (lastDigit == 0)
            q.add(stepNumB);

        else if (lastDigit == 9)
            q.add(stepNumA);

        else {
            q.add(stepNumA);
            q.add(stepNumB);
        }
    }
}

public static void displaySteppingNumbers(Long n, Long m) {

    for (Long i = (long) 0; i <= 9; i++)
        bfs(n, m, i);
}

// Driver code
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Long n = (long) 1;
    Long m = (long) Math.pow(10, 16);


    displaySteppingNumbers(n, m);

}
}
```

Comment: My first observation in running this code is that it is producing numbers which are not stepping numbers (ex. 1309).  Removing these might help.

Comment: Why do you add things to a queue? A simple sequential `for` loop over the range `[n,m]` and a simple function `boolean isSteppingNumber(long num)` requires 0 memory and prints everything in order.

Comment: I'm not sure what an "answer" to this "question" could look like, except for throwing away your code and showing you a proper implementation (and at the time of writing this, the first answer popped up, doing exactly that...). It's not even clear which approach you tried there, and which role the BFS is supposed to play...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may have over thought this. I would start with a method to determine if a single `long` is a stepping number. Using `String.valueOf(long)` to get the `String` representation, and then iterate over the characters in that `String` comparing adjacent values. If the absolute difference of the two digits is not two we return false. After checking all digits, default to `true`. Like,

```
private static boolean isSteppingNumber(long v) {
    char[] arr = String.valueOf(v).toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < arr.length; i++) {
        // The - '0' is really only useful for debugging.
        int a = arr[i] - '0', b = arr[i + 1] - '0';
        if (Math.abs(b - a) != 2) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And, in case it helps, you could do that with a lambda like

```
private static boolean isSteppingNumber(long v) {
    char[] arr = String.valueOf(v).toCharArray();
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length - 1)
            .allMatch(i -> Math.abs(arr[i + 1] - arr[i]) == 2);
}
```

Next, a loop from `n` to `m` (and I would prefer the primitive `long` type). Like,

```
public static void displaySteppingNumbers(long n, long m) {
    LongStream.rangeClosed(n, m).filter(x -> isSteppingNumber(x))
            .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: It is working,but how do I optimize the time,seems like a brute force correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: [The Developer Insight Series, Part 1: Write Dumb Code -- Advice From Four Leading Java Developers](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/devinsight-1-139780.html), [premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) and [Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan)

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct idea in that you can search the numbers like you would a graph. But to get them in the correct order, I'd recommend a min priority queue instead of a queue.

There was one other problem with your implementation - you did not correctly check the bounds on adjacency, e.g. if lastDigit is greater than 7 then lastDigit+2 isn't adjacent.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void displaySteppingNumbers(Long m, Long n) {
        PriorityQueue<Long> heap = new PriorityQueue<>();
        for (Long i = 1L; i <= 9L; i++) {
            heap.add(i);
        }

        while (heap.peek() <= n) {
            Long steppingNumber = heap.poll();
            System.out.println(steppingNumber);
            Long lastDigit = steppingNumber % 10;
            if (lastDigit >= 2)
                heap.add(steppingNumber * 10 + lastDigit - 2);
            if (lastDigit <= 7)
                heap.add(steppingNumber * 10 + lastDigit + 2);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String []args){
        Long m = 100L;
        Long n = 300L;

        displaySteppingNumbers(m, n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post pseudo in the future.
here is the output for the first 1000 numbers from your program:

```
1 9 13 97 131 135 975 979 
2 20 24 202 242 246 
3 31 35 309 313 353 357 
4 42 46 420 424 464 468 
5 53 57 531 535 575 579 
6 64 68 642 646 686 690 
7 75 79 753 757 797 
8 86 90 864 868 902 
9 97 975 979
```

I just added a `/n` before each bfs call.
it's actually a fun little puzzle
write out the output for a set of numbers
you will find a link with binary where 0 represents
a decrement by two in the sequence and 1 and increment of 2 in the
sequence i.e. number `131357` could be written as:
`110111` then you just have to find all the binary numbers between
a given range and that's your solution :D